# How to get tk <<ListboxSelect>> event from keyboard scroll

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, listboxitem

Does anyone know of a way to have a tk.listbox selection change AS I scroll up and down with the up/down keyboard keys?

At present I get an event from a Mouse click.

But if I scroll to the list entry with the up/down keys I don't get an event until AFTER i hit the spacebar.

What I would like is for curselection() to change automatically as I scroll without having to commit with the spacebar. I want to eliminate the need for the spacebar by having the listbox selection change with each up or down key press.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def onlbclick(evt):
    w=evt.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value=w.get(index)
    messagebox.showinfo("Listbox Select",'You selected listitem %d: "%s"',  % (index, value))



root =  Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("List Box Test")
fr = Frame(root, width=200, height=200,bg="grey")
fr.pack()

lb=Listbox(fr,selectmode="SINGLE",bg="white")
lb.insert(1,"blah")
lb.insert(2,"blah blah")
lb.insert(3, "blah blah blah")
lb.insert(4, "blah blah blah blah")
lb.grid(row=1, rowspan=10, column=0,columnspan=5, sticky='W', /
padx=5, pady=5,ipadx=5, ipady=5)
lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onlbclick)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's a short sample version to demonstrate the issue. 
Run the code. Click any item in the list box and you get a messagebox with the text of the list item you clicked.  Now without using the mouse, use the up or down arrow keys on the keyboard and scroll through the list. In order to trigger a selection change event you must press the spacebar.

Comment: please show an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also help if you told us what platform you're running on.

Comment: Edited: with minimal example. Running Python 3.x sorry to be vague, but I have 3 different versions of python 3 running on 3 different systems 2 Linux and 1 Mac it's the same on all.

Comment: your code has syntax errors, so this can't possibly be actual code that gives the behavior you describe. Please show actual, running code, and set the `selectmode` attribute to `BROWSE` (no quotes).

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe is what you get when `selectmode` is set to `"browse"`, which is the default setting.

In your edited example you are setting the `selectmode` to `"SINGLE"`. **This is an invalid mode**. It needs to either be the Tkinter constant `BROWSE` (no quotes) or the literal string `"browse"`:

```
lb=Listbox(fr, selectmode=BROWSE, bg="white")
```

-or-

```
lb=Listbox(fr,selectmode="browse",bg="white")
```

Comment: I've tried both BROWSE and SINGLE selectmode, and the behavior is the same. I want to choose only a single item from the list box. If I click an item on the list I get an event, and then use the up down arrow keys I'd like for the Selection to change with each move. This isn't the case. I have to actually use the space bar to Select an entry after moving to it with the keys. This appears to be the case in ALL modes.

Comment: @JackGalt: without seeing your code it's impossible for us to know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Edited with short example

Comment: @JackGalt: you are setting an invalid selectmode I've updated my answer. This is a perfect example of why you should include actual code in your questions.

Comment: Thanks Bryan but I tried both versions of browse before posting here originally. It still functions the same way. I still have to hit the space bar to execute the curselection()

Comment: @JackGalt: when I take the exact code you posted, replace the popup window with a print statement (because the popup removes the focus), fix the syntax errors, and set `selectmode` to `"browse"` it works as documented. I've tested this on linux, mac and pc, python2 and 3. Bottom line, if you have to use the spacebar to set the value, you're setting the  selectmode incorrectly. I don' t think there can be any other explanation.

Comment: Bryan, thanks a million! Never thought about the focus being the issue. Tested with Print instead of Messagebox and the list maintains focus and it works without the space.  Thanks for the assist!